# I'm confused which article to use, "an" or "the"

Tags: articles

I'm reading an ebook and am getting confused whether to use the article *an* or *the*.

The below lines are shown in my ebook:

> While fragments enable you to compartmentalize your UI into various
>   configurable parts, the real power of fragments is realized when you
>   add them dynamically to activities during runtime. In the previous
>   section, you saw how you can add fragments to **an** activity by modifying
>   the XML file during design time. In reality, it is much more useful if
>   you create fragments and add them to activities during runtime.This enables you to create a customizable user interface
>   for your application.
>
> **For example**:    if the application is running on a smartphone,
>   you might fill
>   **an** activity with a single fragment; if the application is running on a tablet, you might then fill **the** activity with two or more
>   fragments, as the tablet has much more screen real estate compared to
>   a smartphone.

I need to know which one is appropriate, either *an* or *the*. Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: The second one is "the" simply because the two sentences are connected and in the second sentence they are talking about the activity from the first.

Comment: what is *filling* an activity?

Comment: Can you add a sentence or two that comes before what you've quoted? More context might rule out one of the choices.

Comment: post edited clearly please check it now @EsotericScreenName

Comment: @MaulikV post edited

Comment: Stephen, what is it you do not understand? Do you have an additional question?

Comment: @fluffy if something is already spoken we can use `the` instead of `an`?

Comment: @fluffy you can post as an answer because you are one answered first in comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example follows the standard rule that we use the indefinite article for objects we are introducing, and the definite for ones we have already introduced.

The two sentences you quoted are related, they are talking about the same activity. That is why when you mention it for the first time you say "an activity" and when you talk about it for a second time it is something familiar, so you say 'the activity".

Answer (score 2):

You use the indefinite article "an" or "a" when talking in general, when your statement apply to any of the possible subjects.

You use the definite article "the" when talking about a particular subject.

Your example first uses "an" to talk about any of the activities. It then uses "an" to select any one of the activities as an example, but it's not important which. It then uses "the" to talk about the particular activity it just selected.

Answer (score 1):

As the sentence starts speaking about the activity for the first time, 'an' is used. As the activity is made familiar to us, in the second sentence, 'the' is used.

Answer (score 0):

Use "A" if the noun you are describing starts with a consonant.
Example : A book in the closet.

Use "An" if the noun you are describing start with a vowel. (a,e,i,o,u).
Example : "An elephant in the zoo".

"A"/"An" versus "The":
Use "A/An" if you are referring to - GENERAL IDEA.
Ex: A university in the Philippines. (so many universities)

Use "The" if you are referring to - SPECIFIC IDEA.
Ex: The University of the Philippines. (only one University of the Philippines)